# How do i stop push notifications when user is already in the chat room

Tags: websocket, push-notification, socket.io, notifications, messaging

i need some help with the sudo code logics to how i could build a messaging feature, where when the user is already viewing the chat/chatroom, he does not see notifications (push/websockets) being sent to him for that particular chat room, but still will be receiving notifications from other chat/chatroom.